# How do I access a desired item within a list?

Tags: vb.net, list, collections

I am converting previous VB6 code to .Net (2012) and am creating a class that contains data that used to be in an array.

```
Structure defIO
  dim Index as integer
  dim Name as string
  dim State as Boolean
  dim Invert as Boolean
end structure
public IO(128) as defIO
```

Now I can access each element within the array:  IO(3).Name = "Trey"

Since I want to add some functionality of this arrayed structure, I created a class. This holds the data and will do some manipulation within the class for me (inverting the data if required etc.).  I then created the class and generated a list of the class.

```
Public Class clsIO

    Private Shared pState As Boolean
    Private Shared pInvert As Boolean
    Private Shared pIndex As Integer
    Private Shared pName As String

    Public Sub New()
        Try
            pState = False
            pInvert = False
            pIndex = 0

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Exception caught!" & vbCrLf & ex.TargetSite.Name & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Property Name As String
        Get
            Name = pName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            pName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Property State As Boolean
        Get
            State = pState
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If pInvert = True Then
                pState = Not value
            Else
                pState = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Property Invert As Boolean
        Get
            Invert = pInvert
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            pInvert = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Property Index As Integer
        Get
            Index = pIndex
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            pIndex = value
        End Set
    End Property

    End Class


    DInList.Add(New clsIO() With {.Index = 0, .Name = "T1ShutterInPos", .Invert = False, .State = False})
    DInList.Add(New clsIO() With {.Index = 1, .Name = "T2ShutterInPos", .Invert = False, .State = False})
    DInList.Add(New clsIO() With {.Index = 2, .Name = "T3ShutterInPos", .Invert = False, .State = False})
    DInList.Add(New clsIO() With {.Index = 3, .Name = "RotationPos1", .Invert = False, .State = False})
    DInList.Add(New clsIO() With {.Index = 4, .Name = "RotationPos2", .Invert = False, .State = False})
    DInList.Add(New clsIO() With {.Index = 5, .Name = "RotationPos3", .Invert = False, .State = False})
```

Now I want to access a particular element within the list:

```
DInList(1).Name = "Test"
```

This does not work. I do not know how to access a particular element within the list without looping through all the items within the list.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `DInList`?

Comment: I don't see your declaration of `DInList`.

Comment: Also, what does "This does not work" mean?  Be specific.

Comment: Based upon what you wrote and assuming you wrote your DInList declaration as `Dim DInList as New List(Of clsIO)`, it should work...

Comment: Did you mean to make your private variables shared? That means they belong to the class, and not the instances of your objects.

Comment: Public WithEvents DInList As New List(Of clsIO)

Comment: Not working means: When I try to access DInList(1).name or DInList(18).name (I have 20 items in the list), I get the same result - the Name of the last item in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `Shared` keyword from your class variable declarations. You're defining those as class variables so each instance of the class doesn't have its own copy. That means the last update overwrites the previous and changing any object of that class will affect them all.